# string-set! not working in Racket

Tags: scheme, racket

Following code is giving error:

```
(define s "test")
(string-set! s 0 #\T)
```

The error is:

```
  string-set!: contract violation
  expected: (and/c string? (not/c immutable?))
  given: "test"
  argument position: 1st
  other arguments...:
```

How can I change a character of 's' using `string-set!` function? I think it has to be made "mutable". How can that be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because a string defined using the default reader is immutable; it's literally the first thing stated in the [documentation](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/strings.html). For example, to turn it into a mutable string:

```
(define s (string-append "test"))
(string-set! s 0 #\T)
```

It works as expected:

```
s
=> "Test"
```

Comment: Thanks. How do I know which string functions produce mutable stings and which produce immutable strings?

Comment: Check the linked docs, look for the procedures mentioning a "new mutable string".

Comment: The first thing stated in the documentation is "A string is a fixed-length array of characters."